# How to split a line without splitting words in .net

Tags: .net, regex, f#

Is there an easy way to split a line of text into a sequence of shorter lines given some maximum upper bounds without splitting words unless the word itself is longer than that upper bound?

Answer (score 4):

You could match the following regular expression, which limits line length to 40 characters. Each match is a non-empty line of maximum length that begins and ends with a non-whitespace character, contains no more than 40 characters and does not break substrings of non-whitespace characters in the given string, unless such a substring contains more than 40 non-whitespace characters, in which case it is broken after the 40th character.

```
\S{40}| *\r?\n|\S.{0,38}\S(?!\S)
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/3SMnkV/5/)

For the string:

```
All good programmers should take note and come to the aid of their company's bowling team.

Moreover, they should always be mindful that non-words, such as abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefg may need to be split.

Also, blank lines are to be retained.
```

The matches are as follows:

```
          1         2         3       
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789

All good programmers should take note
and come to the aid of their company's
bowling team.

Moreover, they should always be mindful
that non-words, such as 
abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcd
efg may need to be split.

Also, blank lines are to be retained.
```

The regular expression reads, "match 40 non-whites characters or match zero or more spaces, an optional carriage return and a newline or match a non-whitespace character followed by up to 38 characters, followed by a non-whitespace character which is not followed by a non-whitespace character". "Not followed by a non-whitespace character" means the character is followed by a whitespace character or is the last character in the line. `(?!\S)` is a *negative lookahead*.

Comment: you need to detect and split words that exceed the width: `\S{40}|(\S.{0,38}\S(?!\S))`. My version preserved spaces and line separators, but I like your stripping them better. :)

Comment: I interpreted "...split a line of text into a sequence of shorter lines given some maximum upper bounds without splitting words unless the word itself is longer than that upper bound?" to mean, "Is there an easy way to split a line of text into a sequence of shorter lines given some maximum upper bounds without splitting words?  That is only to be done if there is no word that is longer than that upper bound...

Comment: ...Your comment suggests that if there is a word having more than 40 characters, such as "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanokoniosis", you want to to split it, but that didn't occur to me because you gave no rules for splitting. Here I'm thinking of English text, where words should only be split between syllables. Btw, that appears to be the only English word having more than 40 letters. (It has 46.) Side note: I don't understand why you have `\S{40}|` in the regex in your comment, as `\S.{0,38}\S(?!\S)` is also satisfied if the string has exactly 40 non-whitespace characters.

Comment: An English language syllabic split was not a requirement. The notion of word was merely non-whitespace sequence of characters. The requirement was also lossless. Your solution skips words longer than the maximum width and strips breaking whitespace characters, including new line characters within it. Nonetheless, I like the whitespace stripping but the word skipping is a problem, hence the, `\S{40}` which consumes word in max width chunks.

Comment: I understand (finally). I'll give some thought on how to handle newlines. Suggestions?

Comment: I revised my answer, but I'm not confident it meets your requirements because it does drop spaces. Perhaps you are looking for something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xuBnBI/3/) instead.

Comment: Your whitespace stripping was fine and perhaps a simplifying improvement as I noted in my first comment. In retrospect, whitespace sequences should be fungible in the requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This question is old but a Regex solution seems cleaner given the presence of a NextMatch() method and quantification, {n,m}, features in the Regex. The following splits words only if they exceed the given maximum width, `n`, but otherwise splits the line at the last white space character up to and including that. Blank lines are preserved. The template string is reconstructed each time with the given width and then walks over the given text capturing portions of lines progressively.

```
//F# 4.7 using .net regex
open System
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let narrowParagraph: int -> string -> string seq = fun n s ->

  let pattern = sprintf @"(?sx) \w{%d} | [^\r\n]{0,%d} (\s|\r?\n|\r)" n (n - 1)

  Regex.Match(s, pattern) 
  |> Seq.unfold (fun (m:Match) -> 
    if m.Success 
    then Some(m.Value, m.NextMatch()) 
    else None
    )
```